# mysterious data on http response on php

Tags: php, sockets, http, response

I wrote a lightweight http lib for php, everything works fine except the response is exceeds a certain size. The request is made with a stream_socket_client.

Everything works finde until the response body contains larger data then some kind of padding is inserted in the data
eg:

f7c
[{key: value}, {key: value}, {key: value}, {key: value} ... 1000 {key: value}, {key: value}, {key: value}, ...] 1000

in this example the "f7c" and "1000" in the middle and end are not in the original response body

code for parsing response:

```
    private function parseInputStream($stream){
        $header = [];
        $body = "";
        $isHeaderParsed = false;
    
        while (!feof($stream)) {
            $line = fgets($stream, 1024);
            if (!$isHeaderParsed){
                if ($line === "\r\n"){
                    $isHeaderParsed = true;
                    continue;
                } else {
                    array_push($header, str_replace("\r\n", "", $line));
                }
            } else {
                $body .= $line;
            }
        }
        $this->parseHeader($header);
        $this->parseBody($body);
    }
```

Any ideas where these values came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you don't show what request you send and what response header you get my guess is that you send a `HTTP/1.1` request and that the response header contains `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. In this case the request body is not a single piece with the length defined by the `Content-length` header but instead the request body is send in multiple chunks, each prefixed by its length in hex. See [the relevant part of the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1) for more information.

Comment: perfect forgot the chunked part in http, thanks solved it